# How Can I Create a Button that links to multiple websites randomly?

Tags: button, random, hyperlink

I just wanted to know how can I create a button that can take a person to multiple websites in a random order when it is clicked each time. I do not want these websites to open all at once, only one at a time. I'm looking for something similar to the "stumble" button that is used on StumbleUpon. I plan on using this button for a toolbar that I'm planning to create so if anyone here can answer this question I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you weren't really that interested in it if you don't read your answers..

Answer (score 4):

Make a JS array with the target URLs, and randomly pick from it when the button is clicked.

Here is a working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urls = [
        "http://www.kittenwar.com/",
        'http://heeeeeeeey.com/',
        'http://eelslap.com/',
        'http://www.staggeringbeauty.com/',
        'http://www.omfgdogs.com/',
        'http://burymewithmymoney.com/',
        'http://www.fallingfalling.com/',
        'http://ducksarethebest.com/',
        'http://www.republiquedesmangues.fr/',
        'http://www.trypap.com/',
        'http://www.hristu.net/',
        'http://www.partridgegetslucky.com/',
        'http://www.rrrgggbbb.com/',
        'http://www.sanger.dk/',
        'http://www.geodu.de/',
        'http://beesbeesbees.com/',
        'http://breakglasstosoundalarm.com/',
        'http://www.koalastothemax.com/',
        'http://grandpanoclothes.com/',
        'http://www.everydayim.com/',
        'http://www.haneke.net/',
        'http://instantostrich.com/',
        'http://r33b.net/',
        'http://cat-bounce.com/'
    ];

    function goSomewhere() {
        var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
        window.location = url; // redirect
    }
</script>
```

And here is a link with this onClick handler assigned.

```
<a href="#" onClick="goSomewhere(); return false;">Gimme something weird!</a>
```

You can style it to look like a button, if you want.

---

Just FYI the crazy links come from [TheUselessWeb's list](http://www.theuselessweb.com/js/uselessweb.js).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I actually have another question. For HTML Component on the website that I'm using to create my toolbar, there already is an outline of how it should be setup. Here it is:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<!--
Uncomment out the below script reference as needed.  For more information on using the API, please consult http://www.conduit.com/Developers/overview.aspx
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://api.conduit.com/BrowserCompApi.js"></script>
-->
<style type= "text/css">
<!--
BODY {margin-left:0; margin-right:0; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;
width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background-color:threedface;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ENTER YOUR HTML HERE -->

</body>
</html> Is there anyway I can still do this using this code?

Comment: Then ask it as another question, I gave you answer for what you wanted.